# Only acting on files which have the same filename structure in C#

Tags: c#

I have a directory which I am watching for files to be added. when files are added my program kick in and does stuff with the contents of the file.
However, I have different files with different filename structures. The aim of the program is to deal with all the files that have the same structure first, then move on to the next etc. Heres an example:

```
BT424HH-4294967298-4294967301-201807021436.xml
BT424HH-4294967298-4294954545-201807034543.xml
BT424HH-4294967298-4294934543-201807028768.xml
BT424HH-4294955655-4294921321-201807065465.xml
BT424HH-4294955655-4294932422-201807023243.xml
```

In this case I have three files with the same starting structure:

```
BT424HH-4294967298
```

I would like to create a new XML file, parse the contents of the three files into one file, once thats completed, move on to the rest of the files in the directory and do the same (create a new file and parse the xml from the files into a new file)

```
 string[] files = Dir.Split('-');
 string FilePostcode = files[0];
 string FileIdentifier = files[1];
 string currentLocation = FilePostcode + FileIdentifier;
```

However Im not too sure how to deal with the loop for the files, as in this case I only want the first three with the same name before I deal with the next two with the same name.

I hope this makes sense...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just `Group` your files `By` the key you want:

```
public static string GetGroupIdentifier(string path)
{
   var file = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path);

   // take only the first two parts
   var id = string.Join("-", file.Split('-').Take(2));

   return id;
}

public static void GroupFilesInFolder(string path)
{
    foreach(var fileGroup in Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.xml").GroupBy(GetGroupIdentifier))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("For identifier " + fileGroup.Key);
        foreach(var file in fileGroup)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(" - " + file);
        }

        // insert logic to merge the files for this key and do something with the result
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, how would I know when its the last file in the group?

Comment: You could replace the `foreach` with a simple `for` loop, but there is probably better way to achieve what you want. Why do you need to know whether a file is the last file in the group?

Comment: Just so I can append the closing xml to the file, close it, then move on to the next group of files and create a new xml file from them. :-)

Comment: Just close it when the foreach-loop over the files is done?

Answer (score 2):

Directory.GetFiles(string, string) allows you to search a directory for all files matching a pattern.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f(v=vs.110).aspx

If you have a list of all the starting structures in `patterns`:

```
foreach(var pattern in patterns)
{
    foreach(var file in Directory.GetFiles(path, pattern))
    {
        //Merge files
    }
}
```